# JAVA :access method defined in class , but not implemented by its interface

Tags: java, oop

Interface:

```
public interface InterfaceA {
    public void PartOfIinterfaceA();
}
```

Class:

```
public class Class_To_Test_Interface_encapsulation implements InterfaceA {

public void MethodM() {

}

@Override
public void PartOfIinterfaceA() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Main class:

```
public class MainClass {


public static void main(String args[]) {

    InterfaceA Ia = new Class_To_Test_Interface_encapsulation();
     Ia.MethodM();
}
}
```

Its giving me following error :
The method MethodM() is undefined for in type InterfaceA()
I very well know, why its giving me error and its logical.
Also, I refrred , //[Use methods declared in implementation that are not defined in interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732910/use-methods-declared-in-implementation-that-are-not-defined-in-interface)

But, my question is, is there any other way we can , where a piece of code referring to an instance of B
(with type InterfaceA) can in fact access m ?

Comment: Downcast it to `B`?

Comment: In general: if you need to use a method from a class `C`, then you should have the reference stored in a variable of type `C`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to access m on an object (InterfaceA) that doesn't have m (the method is not defined in the interface).  If you know that a subset of InterfaceA will have m defined, you need to determine membership in that subset before accessing m:

```
if (Ia instanceof Class_To_Test_interface_encapsulation) {
  ((Class_To_Test_interface_encapsulation)Ia).MethodM();
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the solution. I have found an alternate solution as well as posted below.

Answer (score -1):

InterfaceA Ia = new Class_To_Test_Interface_encapsulation().MethodM();

This will skip compile time error, and resolve at runtime correctly and call the method MethodM()

Comment: Um. `new Class_To_Test_Interface_encapsulation().MethodM()` evaluates to `void`. You cant assign it to an `InterfaceA`.

Comment: new Class_To_Test_Interface_encapsulation() is a child type of Interface. So when i create a new objcet of that class it would definitely gets assigned to interface which gets resolved at run-time and than the method from the class Class_To_Test_Interface_encapsulation().MethodM() gets called. From where does void came from ? can you have a look at  my original code once again

Comment: The compiler sees `InterfaceA Ia = Class_To_Test_Interface_encapsulation().MethodM();` as `InterfaceA Ia = (new Class_To_Test_Interface_encapsulation().MethodM())`. It will call `MethodM` and assign the result of that to `Ia`, which is not compatible with type `void`. Your solution doesn't even compile: https://ideone.com/NE8dV4

Comment: I have tried it ....it's compiling and running in eclipse... I am still not getting your point with void?

Comment: What I am saying is that the solution you have posted cannot work. When you do `new Class_To_Test_interface_encapsulation()`, the result is of type `Class_To_Test_interface_encapsulation`. When you call the `MethodM()` on it, `MethodM` returns a result of type `void`. When the compiler sees the entire line, it see the type of the right hand expression is of type `void` (that's what `MethodM()` returns) and it thinks you are trying to effectively assign that type to `InterfaceA`. As the linked ideone.com example shows, `void cannot be converted to InterfaceA`. *something* is missing.

Comment: Hey, apologies to miss your point. Now I got it. It worked only when I do this                                                                                                      public InterfaceA MethodM() {
  
  return new Class_To_Test_Interface_encapsulation();
 }   and than call the above method in Main using                InterfaceA Ia = new Class_To_Test_Interface_encapsulation().MethodM();                          Not sure whether this is the correct solution to my problem

Comment: It probably isnt, but at least now we understand how your solution works. Thanks for explaining it!